# A property of constructible elements over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

We say $a$ is constructible over $\mathbb{Q}$,when there exists a chain of quadratic field extension from $\mathbb{Q}$ ending up with a field contains $a$.

I feel it difficult to prove this property:

If $a$ constructible, then there exists a chain of quadratic extension

$$\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_1\rightarrow…\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_n=\mathbb{Q}(a).$$

The most difficult part is that the last field is required to be $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

And note that this is not really true:

$$[K:F]≥[K∩L:F∩L] \text{  for the field  } K,L,F$$

So, how to prove this?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The property you request to prove is just a reformulation of the definition.

Comment: By the definition,the last field only require to contain $a$.But not necessarily $\mathbb{Q(a)}$

Comment: It is easy to prove that if $a$ is constructible, then any $\frac{p}{q}a$ is constructible for $p,q \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: For example,it might happen that the last field is $\mathbb{Q(a,b)}$for some $b$,how to avoid this?

Comment: Let $\mathbb G$ be the Galois closure of $\mathbb Q(a)$, and consider the intersection of your chain of fields with $\mathbb G$. We have $[\mathbb F_{i+1}:\mathbb F_i]\geq[\mathbb F_{i+1}\cap\mathbb G:\mathbb F_i\cap\mathbb G]$, by the result in the middle of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4371081/472818).

Comment: Though what you said is correct,how to provide the final field to be $Q(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the splitting field of minimal polynomial of $a$, Consider the group $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q})$ which is of cardinality $2^{\ell}$ for some $\ell$. If the group $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q})$ is non-trivial then there exists an element $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q})$ of order $2$ and if you consider the fixed field of $\sigma$, call it $L_1$ then we have $[\mathbb{Q}(a):L_1] = 2$. We can keep proceeding by trying to find an element of order $2$ in $Aut(L_1/\mathbb{Q})$ and finding $L_2$ which is the fixed field of this order $2$ automorphism and so on until we find $L_i \subset \mathbb{Q}(a)$ such that $Aut(L_i/\mathbb{Q}) = \{e\}$. This is because for $j>i$ if $[L_j:L_{j-1}] > 2$ then wlog $L_j = L_{j-1}(a_1,...,a_{\ell})$ and all $a_i$ has minimal polynomial of degree $2$ over $L_{j-1}$ and hence $L_j/L_{j-1}$ extension can be written as series of quadratic extensions. Take $r \in L_i \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ then $r$ is constructible and hence if $i \geq 1$, by induction we write it as a series of quadratic extension all of which has trivial automorphism group as otherwise you can extend it to a non-trivial automorphism of $L_i$. But then in any non-trivial quadratic extension Automorphism group is non-trivial since both roots are present in the extension. Hence a contradiction. Hence we have $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}) = \{e\}$. But then by the other answer by wsh there exists an element $b$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(b) \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(a)$. But then $b$ is constructible and by induction has a chain of quadratic extensions and hence non-trivial automorphism and hence a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you.But why can you assume wlog $L_j = L_{j-1}(a_1,...,a_{\ell})$?

Comment: because $L_{j-1}$ is the fixed field of $\sigma$ of order 2 and minimal polynomial of $a_i \in L_j \setminus L_{j-1}$ is $(x-a_i)(x-\sigma(a_i))$ so of degree $2$

Comment: Ok,I think you are correct.And you have proved another property that for all contractible $a$,$Aut(Q(a)/Q)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: If you are convinced then accept my answer by clicking on the left side of my answer.

Comment: Could you find a method to avoid the step to find $b$?that is,avoid using the nontrivial lemma for the nilpotent group?See my last step of the proof.

Comment: Nothing on top of my head, Your proof is nice though.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: suppose that $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}_1\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow\mathbb{K}_m$ is a chain of quadratic extensions with $a\in\mathbb K_m$; then consider the fields $\mathbb{F}_1=\mathbb{K}_1\cap\Bbb Q(a)$, $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{K}_2\cap\Bbb Q(a)$, ..., $\mathbb{F}_m=\mathbb{K}_m\cap\Bbb Q(a)$.

Comment: Thanks.But how to show $[\mathbb{F}_i:\mathbb{F}_{i-1}]$ is quadratic or degree 1?

Comment: @Fishbane thank you,but I still cannot make it clear,can you show me the detail of your hint?

Comment: @Fishbane I don't think it obviously.I find somehow a counterexample so that it is not held in general.See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034410/comparison-of-degrees-of-field-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I have proved my question by Galois theory.

We say $a$ is constructible over field $\mathbb{F}$ if there exist a chain of quadratic extensions begin from $\mathbb{F}$ and contains $a$ somewhere.

Firstly,if $a$ is constructible over arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$ with character 0 and $f_a$ is minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{F}$, then all roots of $f_a$ is constructible.So Galois group of $f_a$,denoted by $G$, is a 2-group,thus nilpotent.Denote the splitting field of $f_a$ by $\mathbb{K}$

Secondly, do induction of the $log_2$ of the degree of $a$.

$n=1$ case is done automorphically for $a$ is degree 2 over $\mathbb{F}$.

Assume if $n\leq k$,for any character zero field $\mathbb{F}$ and any $a$ constructible and of degree $2^n$ over $\mathbb{F}$,there exists a chain of quadratic extension beginning from $\mathbb{F}$ ending with $\mathbb{F(a)}$.

When $n=k+1$ for any character 0 field $\mathbb{F}$,only need to show that there exists $b$ such that $b$ is not in $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F(b)} \subsetneq \mathbb{F(a)}$.By Galois theory and primitive element theorem,this is equal to say that Galois group of $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{F(a)}$,denoted by $H$, is a proper but not maximal subgroup of $G$ unless $a$ itself a square root over $\mathbb{F}$.

If so,take $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$ and note that if $a$ is real,then any subextension of $\mathbb{Q(a)}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is real automorphically, done.

Finally we claim the property we said about $H$ is true and it follows from the fact that every maximal subgroup of nilpotent group is of index $p$, which is a prime number and in particular $p$-group is nilpotent.

For the proof of the claim,see [Every proper maximal subgroup of a $p$-group $P$ is normal and has index $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763518/every-proper-maximal-subgroup-of-a-p-group-p-is-normal-and-has-index-p)

Comment: You have shown that there exists an element $b$ then from this point how would you conclude ? because $[Q(a):Q(b)]$ need not be $2$ ?

Comment: Thank you,now I will change my assumption of the field to be arbitrary character 0 field and use induction.

Comment: @Balaji sb Now we proved base case for arbitrary field with character 0.And $[\mathbb{F(a)}:\mathbb{F(b)}]$becomes strictly smaller so that we can use induction hypotheses.

Comment: OK . but the other answer directly works. Think about it.

Comment: Thank you,if you mean the top answer, I still can not make it clear that how to control the degree of "intersection extension" in this special case,could you show me some details?

Comment: $[K_i \cap Q(a) : K_{i-1} \cap Q(a)] =1 \ or \  2$. One means same field, we can remove it from the chain. Take only 2 degree. At some point it has to become $2$ since $a$ is present in some $K_i$.

Comment: Ok,the point I am confused with is that why the degree you showed above is less or equal to 2,how to prove this,could you give me some details?(not true in general,see the post under the top answer)

Comment: That is,why$[\mathbb{K}_i\cap\Bbb Q(a):\mathbb{K}_{i-1}\cap\Bbb Q(a)]\leq 2$

Comment: If it is not then you can split $[K_i \cap Q(a) : K_{i-1} \cap Q(a)]$ into quadratic extensions by induction using same assumption as yours

Comment: But you are correct in the sense that $K_i \cap Q = Q$ can happen for all $i$.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, i have added an answer, Please take a look.